# Get form name via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have simple question but I can't fined good solution on the web.

I have this HTML code:

```
 <form name="Register" action="Register.aspx" method="post" runat="server" style="margin-top: 15px;" onsubmit="return validateProfile(this);" >
```

And this JavaScript code

```
function validateProfile(F) {
var G = F.name; 
}
```

I want somehow to get the form name, but this code just does not working.

wish for help, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, see the updated code

Comment: have you tried F.name?

Comment: `runat="server"` ... where else would it run?

Comment: Yes, see the updated code pleas

Comment: Why not returning `return validateProfile("Register");`

Comment: @alex23—by what magic did the reference passed to the function morph from a DOM form element into an event object? ;-)

Comment: What you have works fine [here](http://jsbin.com/umaxav/1/).

Comment: I see no reason for a downvote in this question.

Comment: I see no reason for this question.

Comment: Open your console and check if the function is undefined... Maybe your function is not loaded? Anyway, what you have should work for getting the name, don't forget to return `G` in the function..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go

```
function validateProfile(F) {
    alert(F.name); 
    return false;
}
```

`F` is already the form, no need to use `.Form` .

Since a form is an element, you can access its name using [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.name?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.name).

This is defined in the [DOM specification here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-22051454) :

> **name** of type DOMString
>
> Names the form.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5A3up/)

Notice how my JSFiddle contains `window.validateProfile = validateProfile` because I run it after the DOM is ready, if your function is not directly in a script block, chances are you need to do this too.

Comment: `F` is the only reliable reference to the form element, `this` doesn't work with the code OP provided.

Comment: @Jack Thanks. That's a good comment, I've edited it into the answer.

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle, it alerted "Result". changing this "this" to "F" alerts the desired "Register". Oh and I didnt downvote.

Comment: Well, did you realize that `this` in your code actually refers to `window`? :)

Comment: @dan Thanks! I've corrected the fiddle. I did not notice that. I usually do un-obtrusive validation where this is not an issue.

Comment: After your latest edit, it now looks exactly like OP's code :)

Comment: @Jack OP edited his code, his original code was `F.Form.name`

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your answers! I don't know why, but in my site
**F.name** get some empty value like "" why?

Comment: @NaveTseva Would you mind creating a fiddle illustrating your issue? My code works (for your original issue), I can't understand this one you're having, likely people won't be able to either unless you provide more information

Comment: @NaveTseva Notice how my answer says you _have_ to do `window.validateProfile = validateProfile` otherwise, your function is in the closure scope of the onLoad method. (Notice the difference between my fiddle and yours, and try adding that line to yours). http://jsfiddle.net/Hdvst/

Comment: Thank you, in the fiddle it works great, but I can't figure why in my site the same code does not working?! I get empty alert

Comment: @NaveTseva Then instead of accepting the answer, expand your question in a way where this answer still doesn't work; that way we may be able to help you better.

Comment: @NaveTseva I can play the guessing game but I seriously doubt that would help you. Try to isolate the issue, remove parts until you get the smallest code that isn't working. This might be related to the `runat=server` part but I'm not an asp web forms expert (I only know MVC well)

Comment: you absolutly write, sorry, I found the problem the problem is in the runat="server" than I get this code after Debug  '<form method="post" action="Register.aspx" id="ctl00" style="margin-top: 15px;" onsubmit="return validateProfile(this);">'
and the name tag gone, do you know ehy?

Comment: @NaveTseva See if this solves your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/5792306/1348195 . Like I said, I don't use webforms. Honestly, if you're making anything new, I'd seriously consider switching form web forms to MVC, it took me a few weeks to understand, but once I did I became a lot more productive and it was totally worth it. In ASP.NET MVC there are no such surprises

Comment: note that the forms .name attribute can be "polluted" by an input with a name of "name". E.g.

    `<FORM NAME="ActualFormName"> <INPUT NAME="name">`

then the JavaScript will alert with an object (the input) instead of "ActualFormName". At least as far back as IE8, if you use the forms attribute collection, and index the "name" attribute, then it will actually return the correct name. e.g.

    `F.attributes["name"].value;`

Answer (score 3):

You likely have a control in the form with a name of *name*. Form controls are made available as properties of the form, using their name or ID as the property name. So in:

```
<form name="foo" ...>
  <input name="name" ...>
```

then:

```
document.forms['foo'].name
```

returns a reference to the input element, not the value of the form's *name* property (which reflects the value of the HTML name attribute).

The solution is to not use attribute values for form controls that are the same as standard form element attribute or DOM property names (e.g. do not name form controls "submit" or "reset" as they will overwrite the form's *submit* and *reset* methods).

Comment: Sadly, this can be unavoidable. e.g. the guy who designed the database used "name" as a field name, and the action script for posting the data back is not accessable (back end code and you are writing user interface) so you pretty much need to have a text input named "name". In modern browsers, form.getAttribute("name") appears to return the actual forms name, but it doesn't in older browsers.

Comment: Just found out that form.attributes["name"].value works (returning the forms name, not the input object) as far back as IE 8, and I believe IE7.

Answer (score -1):

```
  var  theForms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");  
    for(i=0;i<theForms.length;i++)  
    alert(theForms[i].name);
```

or if you have only one form then use  `theForms [0].name` directly

Answer (score -4):

If you use Jquery. You can get the attr by this :

```
$("form").attr("name"); // Register
```