# how to stop the HTML input property from setting automatically the name attribute

Tags: html, asp.net, input

i have a problem with an input that sets automatically the name attribute witch blocks a javascript code traitement, this is the input code before running it:

```
<asp:textbox ID="replace" runat="server" Name="passchk_pass" type="Password" Size="40"/>
```

and this is how it becomes after running:

```
<input name="ct$Main$ct$Tab$Edu$replace" id="Main_ct_Tab_Edu_replace" type="Password" size="40">
```

so im losing the name that i sets befor in order to get a js traitement, how can i stop the input to set automatically the name attribute?

Comment: this is not connected to any of your tags. This is definitely the ASP behavior

Comment: @smnbbrv so how can i stop it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input name and id changes when set runat=server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792290/input-name-and-id-changes-when-set-runat-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better access the TextBox by ID. You can use a static client ID mode for that.

```
<asp:textbox ID="replace" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Name="passchk_pass" type="Password" Size="40"/>
```

This is not recommended however, since it can lead to duplicate ID's.
Better is to make sure javascript get's the correct ID.

```
var textBoxId = "<%= replace.ClientID %>";
```

But if you really want to use the name to access the TextBox you can use `UniqueID`

```
var textBoxName = "<%= replace.UniqueID %>";
```

Comment: the clientIDMode= "static" helped me with the issue because i changed some thing in the js library. 10'x